# Oracle:Update date column in a table

Tags: oracle10g

Following is my oracle update query that`s throwing error--

Update table Set col1 = To_date(:dateFill, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') Where Fil1 = :ID;

dateFill = 01/05/2012,
  ID= 15

this statement is executing in a procedure,

error -:ORA-01722: invalid number(date field)

Can someone tell me why is 'select To_date('01/05/2012 00:00:00', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;' giving me result like '05-JAN-2012 00:00:00'.???

Please suggest me some answers.

Comment: what is the table datatype for the "Fil1" column is it really a varchar2 by any chance? and the datatype you've defined :ID as is number I assume?

Comment: No issue here with 'Fil1' or 'ID' here,problem with the date values.Fil1 is varchar2,'ID' is a variable of varchar2.

Comment: you say it's running in a procedure, show us how you're binding the values (dbms_sql/execute immediate), as ":id" is only valid if we're talking dynamic sql. also how do you know the error is on the date part?

Comment: Not sure if you noticed that your date format is `'mm/dd/yyyy'` which interprets `'01/05/2012'` as `January 5, 2012`. Which is why your result is '`05-JAN-2012`...'.

Answer (score 1):

If dateFill = 01/05/2012, why are you specifying a date format that includes "hh24:mi:ss"?

Comment: what`s wrong in doing that??oracle will accept 24 hour format.

Comment: Then you'd have to supply a string that includes the hh24:mi:ss components. You format picture tells the to_date function how to interpret the string that you have passed to it. You're telling it to interpret certain characters as hour/minute/second but you're not supplying those characters in dateFill

Comment: I don`t have to supply it,by default '00:00:00' will be displayed right?

Comment: it is possible to over specify the format in TO_DATE. the key is that the format has to at least include the components passed in the right format. i.e `to_date('01/02/2012', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')` is valid (though not preferable if the input is always only down to the day) `to_date('01/02/2012 04:12', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24')` is not as you've not accounted for minutes (ora-01830).

Comment: @user1495475 I believe that is correct for the time component, but be careful of assuming it's correct for other components -- I believe that in some cases omitted components are set to the corresponding value from sysdate. Give it a test, anyway.

Comment: It will be only date i`m sending not time.

Comment: Hence, do not include the time component in the date format picture.

Answer (score 1):

An ORA-01722 error occurs when an attempt is made to convert a character string into a number, and the string cannot be converted into a valid number. Valid numbers contain the digits '0' through '9', with possibly one decimal point, a sign (+ or -) at the beginning or end of the string, or an 'E' or 'e' (if it is a floating point number in scientific notation).

Answer (score 0):

to_date always work with 'character' ie

```
to_date(char[,'format'[,nls_lang])
```

Your variable `'dateFill'` is of Number datatype. `Cast` or `convert` this 'dateFill'
field into varchar and things will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me why is 'select To_date('01/05/2012 00:00:00',
>   'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;' giving me result like
>   '05-JAN-2012 00:00:00'.???

how a date displays is down to your client / Nls date format setting:

```
SQL> select To_date('01/05/2012 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

TO_DATE('01/05/20120
--------------------
05-jan-2012 00:00:00

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select To_date('01/05/2012 00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

TO_DATE('01/05/2012
-------------------
01/05/2012 00:00:00

SQL>
```